# Ant cleanup if not uptodate

Tags: java, ant

In ANT I have a build file with these targets:
`INIT <-- CLEAN <-- COMPILE <-- TEST`

I would like to keep the build environment clean by removing unnecessary files from previous builds.
The problem is that in the test phase I want to check if test sources are uptodate with test classes, so I don't run tests. To check that I need to compare last build classes with source files, like this:

```
<uptodate property="tests.unnecessary">
    <srcfiles dir="src" includes="**/*.java"/>
    <mapper type="glob" from="*.java" to="${build.dir}/classes/*.classes"/>
</uptodate>
```

So I would like to check if tests are necessary and:
- if they are, clean the classes and re-run compilation and tests;
- if they aren't, don't do anything.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example of the [`uptodate` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/uptodate.html) is close - you probably need to tweak the mapper and take care with absolute versus relative paths.  Perhaps:

```
<uptodate property="tests.unnecessary">
    <srcfiles dir="src" includes="**/*.java"/>
    <mapper type="glob" from="*.java" to="../${build.dir}/classes/*.class"/>
</uptodate>
```

Note the `..` in the mapper `to=` attribute - presumably the `build.dir` is at the same level in the directory hierarchy as `src`.  Also note that the compiled classes have the extension `.class` rather than '.classes'.

Once you've run the above, you can use the `if/unless` attributes of Ant [targets](http://ant.apache.org/manual/targets.html#targets) to control execution.  There are a number of approaches, the most basic might be something like the below.  When `ant test` is run, Ant will determine whether any files are out-of-date, and skip the clean, compile and test if not.  Another approach might be to call a series of target invocations from within a single target using the [`antcall` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/antcall.html).

```
<target name="check" depends="init">
    <uptodate property="tests.unnecessary">
        <srcfiles dir="src" includes="**/*.java"/>
        <mapper type="glob" from="*.java" to="${build.dir}/classes/*.class"/>
    </uptodate>
</target>

<target name="init">
    <echo message="Running init" />
</target>

<target name="clean" depends="check" unless="tests.unnecessary">
    <echo message="Running clean" />
</target>

<target name="compile" depends="clean" unless="tests.unnecessary">
    <echo message="Running compile" />
</target>

<target name="test" depends="compile" unless="tests.unnecessary">
    <echo message="Running test" />
</target>
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what i was searching.. :D